# Robot Framework - Comparing empty string in response JSON to null in DB query result

Tags: json, python-3.x, database, null, robotframework

Using Robot Framework for API testing.

GET query pulls data from a DB.
Some fields have no data.

Comparing the response JSON and the results of SQL query.
In the JSON, an example would be: "FaxNumber": ""
The DB query has the FaxNumber field as null (datatype).

I need to use Should Be Equal As Strings the 2 values.
However, "" != NULL.

How can the nulls in the DB query be converted to and empty string?

I've tried:
${dbResult}=    Evaluate    '${dbResult}' or ''

But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Created a .py file with the following logic:

```
def replacenull(nullvalue):
if nullvalue is None:
    nullvalue = ''
else:
    nullvalue = nullvalue

return nullvalue
```

Added the .py file as a Library in the Settings section of the .robot file.

Then called the function with the data that needed nulls to be handled.